# Is there a way to apply different functions to a nested list by variables in this list?

Tags: r

I have a nested list

```
length_group <- rep(c(1:11), length.out = 1000)
age_group <- rep(c(3:13), length.out = 1000)
trip_group <- rep(c(1:6), length.out = 1000)
vehicle <- rep(c(1:5), length.out = 1000)
value <- c(1:1000)
value <- sample(value, size = 10000, replace = TRUE)

df <- data.frame(length_group, age_group, trip_group, vehicle, value)

n_df <- df %>%
  group_by(length_group, age_group, trip_group) %>%
  nest()
```

I am trying to find a way by which I can multiply the column value by a certain percentage if these values are in a certain trip_group.

For example, I want to multiply the column value in every trip_group == 1 with 0.9, in every trip_group == 2 with 0.45, in every trip_group == 3 with 0.5, in every trip_group == 4 with 0.8, in every trip_group == 5 with 0.7 and in every trip_group == 6 with 1.0.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your trip_group is an integer, you can do:

```
MULT = c(0.9,0.45,0.5,0.8,0.7,1.0)
names(MULT) = 1:6

df %>% mutate(new_value = value * MULT[trip_group]) %>% head()

  length_group age_group trip_group vehicle value new_value
1            1         3          1       1   355    319.50
2            2         4          2       2   743    334.35
3            3         5          3       3   315    157.50
4            4         6          4       4   839    671.20
5            5         7          5       5   769    538.30
6            6         8          6       1   452    452.00
```

if your trip_group is character etc, you can do:

```
df %>% mutate(new_value = value * MULT[as.character(trip_group)]) %>% head()
```

Answer (score 0):

In base R you may do:

```
dat$value.mult <- dat$value * c(.9, .45, .5, .8, .7, 1)[factor(trip_group)]
head(dat)
#   length_group age_group trip_group vehicle value value.mult
# 1            1         3          1       1   993      893.7
# 2            2         4          2       2   694      312.3
# 3            3         5          3       3   437      218.5
# 4            4         6          4       4   203      162.4
# 5            5         7          5       5    71       49.7
# 6            6         8          6       1   746      746.0
```